# How do I delete a character?

Tags: conclave

How do I delete one character on ConClave?

[image]

I searched for "Delete" or something like it. I know, I still have "room" for more characters, but I just want to delete one. There is a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the character's name and click the Delete Character button.

[image]

Comment: Damn! I was trying to "Left-click" it... >.<